# Python link records if match in column

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have following dataframe:

```
 df=pd.DataFrame({'cluster':[1,1,1,2,8],'ssn':['123','','','567','123']})
```

I want to link the records with matching ssns. In this case, I want to link the clusters 1 and 8. The expected output is as below:

```
   cluster  ssn
0       1   123
1       1   
2       1   
3       2   567
4       1   123
```

I am struggling even to define a method to approach this (meaning should I use pivot table, groupby). So, even if I get some direction or suggestion on how may I approach this scenario, I will work on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.groupby.transform`:

```
df['cluster'] = df.groupby('ssn').transform(min)
```

Output:

```
   cluster  ssn
0        1  123
1        1     
2        1     
3        2  567
4        1  123
```

Comment: Perhaps better `df['cluster'] = df.groupby('ssn').ssn.transform('first')`

Comment: @yatu I did think of it, but it could make lower numbered cluster to become higher numbered if the latter comes first, which, IMO, didn't seem to be desired output. Plus, the performances were almost identical (tested with 50k rows) so I took `min` :)